# add new user with URL variable?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i was looking here, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

i was wondering if its possible to add new users with a url string?

for example:
link: http://www.website.com?fname=John&sname=doe&pass=pword&email=my@email.com

some how i would need to parse this and insert it into the wordpress add user function.

wp:

any ideas? possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a file called "create-user.php". Assuming you place that file in your theme directory, the URL you should use would be something like: (your-site).com/wp-content/themes/(theme-name)/create-user.php?u=(some-username)&p=(some-password)&em=(some-email).

What you'll be doing is passing the parameters for the new user via the [GET HTTP Request Method](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). The code would be something like:

```
<?php
$user_id = wp_create_user( $_GET["u"], $_GET["p"], $_GET["em"] );
echo "New user ID is $user_id";
?>
```

You should validate that the user was created properly, but more important you should be careful since you don't want anyone to be able to create users from a public URL.